# Varying Title Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here's what I have in my code, I want to have the words constant but my code to put in the `y1axis`, `y2axis` and `xaxis` strings I define earlier so that the title of the graph I've made can vary depending on what I want to plot.

```
def plt_title():
    title2 = "+y1axis+" and "+y2axis+" vs. "+xaxis+" from April 1"
    return plt.title(title2, y=1.07)
    print plt.title()
```

Comment: what's your question? is it not working /?

Comment: Try removing the first `"+`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have your quotations in the wrong place. Try this:

```
>>> y1axis='Y1 data'
>>> y2axis='Y2 data'
>>> xaxis='X data'
>>> title2 = y1axis + ' and ' + y2axis + ' vs. ' + xaxis + ' from April 1'
>>> print title2
Y1 data and Y2 data vs. X data from April 1
```